# Why isn't tag [announcements] a red moderator tag?

Tags: bug, meta-tags, moderator-tags, announcements

**Sub-question**: Is it true that all Stack Exchange employees are moderators of Meta.SE?

I find there no point in leaving [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) as a regular tag, because everyone can post questions that carry this tag (like this question itself). I think announcements should only be posted by SE employees and Meta.SE moderators.

Comment: At this point in time, yes. All MSE mods are employees, though apparently in the MSO days, trilogy mods had mod powers (I missed all the fun)

Comment: @Journeyman You answered my sub-question reversely. I asked if "all *employees are* moderators", not "all *moderators are* employees".

Comment: Well, not all MSE employees are mods. I believe its just the CM team, and Devs, maybe SRE and a few others.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek or in short, any who have a need for a diamond here.

Comment: I'd guess all employees aren't MSE mods... SE has offices with, I assume, cleaners and kitchen staff etc. I don't think they should be given mod powers here...

Comment: @Cai Then you might probably have forgot gate guards. If there were Hygiene.SE, Chef.SE and PhysicalSecurity.SE, I suppose those staffs should be given mod powers.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking folks like marketing and sales, who're a core part of the business but arn't quite on the side of the business that interacts with us users/content creators. So, I'd say a *subset* of SE staff have this (and mod diamonds) where they need it.

Answer (score 7):

It was [mooted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290662/were-implementing-an-announcement-tag-for-direct-communication-from-the-team?rq=1) to make it a special tag.

Apparently the community hated it - so the special announcements tag was not implemented in that planned form. It may end up being so in future (I know about as much as you do there).

If its used inappropriately, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to politely remove the tag (with an appropriate error message), something we can do *right now* with sufficient reputation.

Comment: That link suggests that a large part of the opposition to this idea 
(a special announcements tag) was due to a particular (political) post.